# Change line priority in plot

Tags: r, plot

I have created a `plot` in which pairs of `points` on different `lines` are connected by line `segments`.  One set of points is represented by open circles.  The end of a line connecting to one of these open circles is visible within that circle.  This creates the appearance of a bullseye.  I would prefer the line not be visible within the open circle.  Can I change the priority of the line to be behind, and obscured by, the open circle?  Alternatively, perhaps it is possible to create open circles filled by white?

Sorry if this is a duplicate question.  I would prefer a black-and-white plot in base `R`.

Here is my `R` code with over-sized points to illustrate the issue:

```
x <- seq(60,80)

fitted <- c(0.60, 0.70, 0.80, 0.20, 0.70, 0.60, 0.70, 0.10, 0.20, 0.80,
            0.75, 0.05, 0.40, 0.20, 0.80, 0.70, 0.30, 0.40, 0.10, 0.20, 0.55)

stat <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)

png('change.line.priority.in.plot.May25.2020.png')

plot(x, fitted, ylab="Probability", xlab="Observation", pch = 16, bty = "l", ylim = c(0,1), cex = 3)

lines(x, stat, type = 'p', pch = 21, lty = 1, cex = 3)

segments(x[2],  stat[2],  x[2],  fitted[2],  lwd = 2, lty = 'dotted')
segments(x[10], stat[10], x[10], fitted[10], lwd = 2, lty = 'dotted')
segments(x[15], stat[15], x[15], fitted[15], lwd = 2, lty = 'dotted')
segments(x[20], stat[20], x[20], fitted[20], lwd = 2, lty = 'dotted')

dev.off()
```

Here is the plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution involved simply adding `bg = 'white'` to the `lines` statement.

```
x <- seq(60,80)

fitted <- c(0.60, 0.70, 0.80, 0.20, 0.70, 0.60, 0.70, 0.10, 0.20, 0.80,
            0.75, 0.05, 0.40, 0.20, 0.80, 0.70, 0.30, 0.40, 0.10, 0.20, 0.55)

stat <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)

png('change.line.priority.in.plot.May25.2020.png')

plot(x, fitted, ylab="Probability", xlab="Observation", pch = 16, bty = "l", ylim = c(0,1), cex = 3)

lines(x, stat, type = 'p', pch = 21, lty = 1, cex = 3, bg = 'white')

segments(x[2],  stat[2],  x[2],  fitted[2],  lwd = 2, lty = 'dotted')
segments(x[10], stat[10], x[10], fitted[10], lwd = 2, lty = 'dotted')
segments(x[15], stat[15], x[15], fitted[15], lwd = 2, lty = 'dotted')
segments(x[20], stat[20], x[20], fitted[20], lwd = 2, lty = 'dotted')

dev.off()
```